# ModHeader Chrome Extenstion with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, robotframework

I am learning to use Robot Framework together with Selenium. I use the Chrome Extension "ModHeader" and I have managed to export it to a crx "zip" file, and then import it in my robot test case:

```
${EXTENSTION PATH}    ./modheader_extension.crx
${chrome options}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
Call Method    ${chrome options}    add_extension    ${EXTENSTION PATH}
Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome options}
Goto    ${BASE URL}
```

The problem arises that the extension is loaded but without any settings, ie, no headers configured.
I need one header, with a key and value set, could someone please help on how this should be done? I have tried to look at documentation and other stack overflow questions. I am new to both Robot framework and python.

Best Regards
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extensions built in https://github.com/bewisse/modheader_selenium, and then navigate to `https://bewisse.com/add?Test=1` to add the header `Test: 1`.